# Getting the SUM of a column in MySQL table and putting it in JTextField

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sum, jtextfield

I am trying to compute for the sum of a column from a MySQL table and putting the result in a JTextField on button-click. Here is the method that computes for the sum:

```
private void computeTotalUnits(JTextField tf) {
        try {
            st = conn.createStatement();
            sql = "SELECT SUM(no_of_units) AS total_no_of_units FROM schedule;";

            rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

            tf.setText(rs.getString(1));

        } catch(Exception ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.toString());
        }
    }
```

However, I am getting an "SQLException: Before start of result set" upon clicking the button.

Comment: Where do you get this exception`? on the executeQuery function or on the getString function?

Comment: Hi, this is the whole [StackTrace](http://pastebin.com/CQMw2gMe). Your kind assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: The StackTrace isn't very usefull if i don't have the full code, but you can debug your project, and put a break at the start of the methode and look step by step what happens and tell us the result or you can insert System.out.println("...")'s with abc or 123 to check where your function stops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing `rs.next()` I guess. See [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/statement-object-example.htm). Also it is possible that sum is not String. Try to get `BigDecimal`

Comment: You are correct. `tf.setText(rs.getString(1));` must be inside `while(rs.next()){}`. After that, it worked. Marked as accepted answer.